# Left view will take up all the space in a horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextView (`tv1` and `tv2`), and I want **tv2** to be on the right of **tv1**, like this:

[short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdINa.png)

or

[long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8tOa.png)

(Sorry I can't embed images because I don't have enough reputation : (

So I make a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="*" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If the `text` of **tv1** is within one line, everything is perfect. But if the `text` is more than one line, **tv1** will take all the space:

[tv1 take all the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ffhq.png)

I think it may be because of Android lays out views in the order in which they appear in the layout file, so I change the root view from LinearLayour to ConstraintLayout and make **tv2** first:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="*"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This still doesn't work. I know I can use `setLayoutParams` to set `tv1`'s width programmatically, but is there any other way besides programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a perfect way to archive this:

1. Change `LinearLayout` to `TableLayout` + `TableRow`
2. Use the `shrinkColumns` attribute of `TableLayout` to specify the zero-based index of the columns to shrink. I set it to `0` because I want **tv1** to be shrinkable so that it will not take up all the space

   ```
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TableRow
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/tv2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="*" />

       </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

At last I managed to make it by using **padding**:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="12sp"
        android:text="HelloWorld"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/tv1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The point is using tv2's right-to-right constraint for tv1, and setting a fixed size width of tv2 and padding-right size of tv1. So tv2 overlays on top (and inside) of tv1.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: While use of layout weight is correct answer, you most likely do not fukly understand how it exactly works, otherwise you wouldn't set it to 0.5 as the value is not directly important here but proportion to other weights is what matters. Setting it both to same value, ie most obvious is just 1, but 5 or 13 would work the same way. So it works not because you set it 0.5 but that you set both the same

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the `layout_weight`, it is used to set the size ratio for each view, but I want `tv2` can be close to `tv1`. Setting both `layout_weight` to same value will make `tv1` and `tv2` each take up half of the space, and that isn't what I want

Comment: @BoomingBones I'm sorry I overlooked that `android:text="*"`. I updated my answer with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Thank you, but this is still not what I want. I edited my question and added some images, please take a look

Comment: @BoomingBones Finally, I rewrote my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Use `padding` to archive this is a good idea, but it isn't responsive. If the user changes the text size or display size of the system, or uses a custom font, the width of **tv2** will change accordingly, which may cause **tv2** to overlap **tv1**

Answer (score 0):

Try this its works for me. You have to set layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1" in both TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="hello world ********** welcome"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="hello world ********** welcome" />

</LinearLayout>
```